# How to compare two arrays of angular with ids and give the output from second array if it match the id of first array

Tags: angular

I have two arrays

first array is

```
arr1  = [
           {id:1,name:"cat1"},
           {id:2,name:"cat2"},
           {id:3,name:"cat3"},
        ];
```

Second array is

```
arr1  = [
           {id:1,cat_id:1,name:"satya"},
           {id:2,cat_id:3,name:"ajay"},
        ];
```

so far I am comparing them with and showing them on result html with this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of arr2;let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let item2 of arr1;let i = index" >
    <span ngIf*="item.cat_id=== item2.id;">
        {{item2.name}}
    </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is showing tables with many spaces blank and not showing the desired result

Comment: Don't put logic in the template. Build the array you want on the component.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your templates as simple as possible. Everytime you add any javascript logic, you should ask yourself if it's not easier to move it to a controller or a service.

Here you could create a new array in the controller of your component which combines the other two based on your logic. Something like this:

```
    combinedArray = arr2.map(el => ({
      ...el,
      ...arr1.find(arr1El => arr1El.id === el.cat_id),
    }));
```

I assumed here that all elements in arr2 have a match with an element in arr1, otherwise you have to add another `.filter` after that `.map`.

Then the template will become super simple:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of combinedArray">
  <td>
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```